# Floodlight Activity Tag Character Requirements

Tags: tags, tagging, double-click-advertising, google-floodlight

The support documentation around DFA Floodlight tags seems to imply that Floodlight activity tag strings need to be 8 characters in length, but it isn't really clear whether or not that's a minimum or maximum length. Does anyone know from experience?

Answer (score 0):

According to GTM, it's the maximum

[image]